# How to find the name of the buffer files in vim?

Tags: vim

How do I find out the name of the files in the buffers in vim.Is there any command that returns the name of the file?

Comment: `:ls` lists buffers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bufname()` command returns the filespec of the passed-in buffer number. To get all buffers (like `:ls`), you can iterate with `for bufNr in range(1, bufnr('$')) ...` The returned filespec may be relative to the current directory; you can use `fnamemodify()` to turn it into an absolute filespec.